# Clear jquery form except few fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, selector, reset

I want to clear a form except few fields. Currently, I have a form with a TinyMCE editor. When I click on a person list, the form is displayed in a popup. The TinyMCE editor is retaining the value of the previous person.

I thought to reset the form but it is removing some preloaded valuable information. So, I can't do that as well.

I want to reset the form with the TinyMCE editor, or at least reset whole form except few fields. The fields are `input`, `select` etc.

I am thinking of adding class `notReset`. The form id is `personal_form`. I am currently using

```
$('#personal_form")[0].reset();
```

I hope to find some solution regarding this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clear the content of a TinyMCE instance, call `setContent('')` on it.

```
tinymce.activeEditor.setContent('');
```

If you have multiple editors you need to clear, loop through the `editors` collection:

```
tinymce.editors.forEach(editor => editor.setContent(''));
```

To clear the other fields, then you can put the class on them to target and set their values as necessary:

```
$(':input.allow-reset').val('');
```

In your case you would need to perform both of these actions when the modal is hidden, so that the form state is ready for the next time the modal is displayed.

Comment: Or, equally, `$(':input:not(.noreset)').val('');` if you don't mind using double-negatives

Comment: Thank you for the information. How can I clear content of all TinyMCE. I have multiple Tinymce textarea.

Comment: Loop through the `tinymce.editors` collection. I updated the answer to give you an example.